# pcap compile syntax error on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, inspiron

When I try to run the command `sudo tcpkill -i wlan0 -9 example.com` it says

```
pcap_compile: syntax error
tcpkill: couldn't initialize sniffing
```

I am running Ettercap to initialize MITM

BTW I'm running this on a Dell Inspiron 14r N4010.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify a hostname but a pcap expression to tcpkill. The expression that's being used in this case is just `example.com` which is invalid. You'd have to use something like `host example.com`. Better yet, if you can use an IP address instead of `example.com` that'd be best.

With these expressions you can select traffic according to a wide variety of criteria, I suggest you have a look to see how things work. Incidentally, this is the same expression syntax used by tcpdump, so if you want to see which packets are being picked up by the filter/expression before using tcpkill on them, you can use tcpdump to test your expressions. Here's a reference on pcap expressions:

http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/pcap-filter/